# Observable values disappearing after being pushed into observableArray

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js, closures

I'm grabbing data from the server and pushing them into an observable array.

I'm pushing observables into an observable array.

As I push the data into the observables, the observables contain the data.

However as soon as I push the observables into the observable Array, a few of the observables are missing data.

```
      self.mealFoods([]);

      $.ajax({
        url: "/mealsurl/1",
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(datad) {

          for(var lia = 0; lia < datad.length; lia++){
            var cats_url = "/catsurl/" + datad[lia].category_id;

            var units_by_food_url = "/unitsurl/" + datad[lia].ndb_no;

            var foodThing = new NewFood();

            foodThing.foodId(parseInt(datad[lia].id)); //works

            foodThing.category(parseInt(datad[lia].category_id)); //works

            $.ajax({
              url: cats_url,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(dat) {
                foodThing.category_foods(dat); //works
              }
            });

            foodThing.food(datad[lia].ndb_no); //works

            $.ajax({
              url: units_by_food_url,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(dat) {
                foodThing.food.units(dat); //works
              }
            });

            foodThing.unit(parseInt(datad[lia].seq)); //works

            foodThing.number_of_unit(datad[lia].this_much); //works



            self.mealFoods.push(foodThing); 

            // At this point when looking inside the mealFoods array: self.mealFoods()[0].food(), self.mealFoods()[0].unit(), self.mealFoods()[0].food.units(), self.mealFoods()[0].category_Foods() ALL ARE EMPTY

          }              
        }
      });
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a jsfiddle deomonstrating the issue? You should also provide the code for NewFood

Comment: hey Wayne. It's weird. It's happening only with server side data. When I fake it - it works.

Comment: I can see the problem now. It's because the Ajax calls are asynchronous. I'll post an answer when I get home

Comment: Actually, your problem is not with Knockout at all, but with the asynchronous execution of ajax!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You, sir, are having a classic case of *async-brain-melt*. It is a common sympton in beginners but never fear for the recovery rate is nearly 100%. :)

I would wager your experience is with *synchronous* languages, that is, where if one line is written after the other, the lines written before are executed before, always.

A normal JavaScript function is synchronous. For example:

```
console.log(1);
console.log(2);
```

As expected, this prints `1` and then `2`.

However, asynchronous code is not necessarily executed in the order it was declared. Consider this example using a *setTimeout* function, which schedules a function for later execution:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(1); }, 1000);
console.log(2);
```

Now, the output will be `2` and `1`, because `1` only ran 1000 millis after the `setTimeout` call.

So, I imagine you are beginning to understand how this applies to your problem.

Your calls to `cats_url` and `units_by_food_url` are **asynchronous**. Therefore, the following code **does not wait** for them to finish. So, when you access `self.mealFoods()[0].food.units()`, the `success` function has not yet grabbed the data!

What you need to do is to **coordinate your asynchronous calls appropriately**. There are many ways to achieve that. First, I'll teach you the most simple strategy, using only functions:

- Grab the list from the server
- When you have the list, iterate over each meal and start two ajax calls (up to here, you are already doing everything right)
- Now comes the magic: when you have the results for **either** ajax call, you call an "itemComplete" function. This function will sync the two calls - it will only proceed if the two calls finished.
- Finally, call a "listComplete" function each time any item is complete. This function must also check if all items are complete before proceeding.

So, it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/meals/1",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(list) {

    var observableArray = ko.observableArray([]); // this will hold your list
    var length = list.length;
    var tries = 0;
    var listComplete = function () {
      tries++;
      if (tries == length) {
        // Hooray! 
        // All your items are complete.
        console.log(observableArray());
      }
    };

    list.forEach(function(item){
      var propertyOneUrl = item.propertyOneUrl;
      var propertyTwoUrl = item.propertyTwoUrl; 

      var propertyOneComplete = false;
      var propertyTwoComplete = false;

      var food = new Food(item.id);

      var itemComplete = function () {
        if (propertyOneComplete && propertyTwoComplete) {
          // This item is complete.
          observableArray.push(food);

          // Let's warn list complete so it can count us in.
          listComplete();
        }
      };

      // Start your ajax calls
      $.ajax({
        url: propertyOneUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (propertyOne) {
          food.propertyOne(propertyOne);
          // Declare that your first property is ready
          propertyOneComplete = true;
          // We can't know which property finishes first, so we must call this in both
          itemComplete();
        }
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: propertyTwoUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (propertyTwo) {
          food.propertyTwo(propertyTwo);
          // Declare that your second property is ready
          propertyTwoComplete = true;
          // We can't know which property finishes first, so we must call this in both
          itemComplete();
        }
      });
    }); //for each
  } // success   
});
```

Now, you probably realize how tiresome that pattern can be. That's why there are other ways to better solve this problem. One of these is a pattern called "Promises". You can learn more about them in these links:

https://www.promisejs.org/
http://blog.gadr.me/promises-are-not-optional/

And you'll be happy to know that jQuery.ajax() returns a Promise! So, now you can try and solve that problem using Promises. You'll end up with a much cleaner code.

Hope you make it!

Comment: That was a brilliant answer. I learned more about JavaScript from this one answer than anything else I've ever done in my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are doing async ajax calls in a loop. Because whenever an ajax call is made it the loop continues it means that by the time the response comes back the object assigned to `foodThing` is now no longer what it was set to before the ajax call. Because a for loop is so quick is most likely that only the last object created in the loop is updated.

If you have a look at this simple loop it has the same problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var a = new NewFood(i);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/catsurl/1",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(dat) {
            console.debug(a.id);
        }
    });
}
```

By the time the ajax call comes back a has changed and what ends up happening is only 9 gets written out 10 times: http://jsfiddle.net/r6rwbtb9/

To fix this we would use a closure which is essentially wrapping the ajax call in a function in which we self contain the item we want to do something with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var a = new NewFood(i);
    (function (a) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/catsurl/1",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(dat) {
                console.debug(a.id);
            }
        });
    })(a);
}
```

And then you can see that the numbers 0-9 are output to the console: http://jsfiddle.net/r6rwbtb9/1/. It's also interesting to note that you can't ensure that each request will necessarily come back in the the same order. That is why sometimes the numbers could come back in a different order to 0-9 because some requests are quicker than others.

SO back to your code. In order to make sure you are updating the correct item for each callback you need to use a closure for each ajax call. There was also a problem with `foodThing.food.units(dat)` which needed to be `foodThing.food().units(dat)` as `foodThing.food()` is an observable.

So to wrap in closures we need to change the two ajax calls to this:

```
(function(category_foods){
    $.ajax({
      url: cats_url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(dat) {
        category_foods(dat); 
      }
    });
})(foodThing.category_foods);

(function(units){
    $.ajax({
      url: units_by_food_url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(dat) {
        units(dat); 
      }
    });
})(foodThing.food().units);
```

Comment: Hey, Wayne. Nice solution. However, I feel you missed explaining why that would work. It seems OP is a beginner. If you could read my answer and tell me if I should add something, I would be very glad. Thanks!

Comment: @gadr90 Yeah. I tried to explain. I really find it hard to explain these things. I'll try to improve it

Comment: @gadr90 I updated it. It's definitely a lot longer now, but hopefully it makes sense.